# Issue displaying geometry in edit mode

Tags: mesh

I have encountered a display issue that I am not quite sure if it is a problem or a feature.

Everything works ok in Object Mode, but when I switch to Edit Mode, the geometry is displayed with a kind of double-border (I don't know how else to describe it!), as if the geometry was the bounding box of some some inner volume (see screenshot below).

[image: default cube with the double-border]

With just the cube this style of display is kind of workable, but when the scene gets crowded, this feature gets increasingly confusing I suspect this is a display feature, but I cannot find its settings anywhere; also, I could not find any information at all concerning the topic (to be honest, I wasn't even sure of the keyword to search); I only found information about the "Limit Selection to Visible" toggle; but I am fully aware of that feature and it works fine. If this display mode is a feature, does anybody know its use and how to disable it to display a solid geometry in Edit Mode?

I am using Blender 2.76b on Windows 7 with 8GB RAM, AMD and 2GB AMD Capeverde.

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Sept

Comment: whoa that is really weird

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. On reviewing the post suggested, I found the solution.

It appears that the 3D clipping property needs to be within reasonable ranges, otherwise the edit mode display will be deformed; my viewport clipping ranged between 1 cm and 10 kilometers at the time I experienced the problem; when I dropped the end-clipping to 1 km, the problem with the weird display in the viewport disappeared.

It is interesting to note that exactly the same happens with camera view; if the camera clipping settings are outside a certain range, the geometry will show the double-border in edit mode, although only in camera view.

I found that The clipping range 1cm to 1km in metric (or .001 and 1000 in generic blender units) works well for both viewport and camera views.

I hope this information is of use.

Regards,

Sept